# Windows CMD Batch File Run A Command as Administrator

Tags: cmd, administrator, runas, appcmd

I have a batch file where I want to run some commands, but not all of them as administrator.  I do not want to run the command prompt as administrator or run the entire batch job as administrator.  An example of a command that I want to run as administrator is:

`appcmd.exe recycle apppool \apppool.name -DefaultApp`

Appcmd is the command for managing IIS 7, and this example I want to recycle an App Pool.
I have tried:

`runas /profile /user:MYPC\administrator "appcmd.exe recycle apppool \apppool.name -DefaultApp"`

I get a `1326: Logon failure: unknown user or bad password`, but I know the user and password exist.  Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that running `runas` without the `/profile` parameter worked fine.  But if you must run it with `/profile` then you could execute this command just prior:

```
runas /profile /user:MYPC\administrator "cmd"
```

Which will unfortunately prompt you twice.