# Windows uninstaller isn't running as Admin

Tags: windows, registry, admin, uninstallation

I've made a custom installer / uninstaller.  I register the uninstaller with the Windows Registry as described in the [MSDN Library, Chaper 2. Install/Uninstall.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954376.aspx)

Namely, this means registering `uninstall.exe` as the `UninstallString`.  It works, in that it runs my uninstaller.  The problem is that it doesn't invoke as admin.  I've set `uninstall.exe`'s manifest to require admin using `mt`, and if you double-click it from explorer, it will automatically request admin as desired.

So the question is, what's the magic flag I need to set in the registry to get the Windows Add / Remove Programs dialog to run my uninstaller as admin?

Answer (score 0):

You could add checking for admin privileges inside your uninstall program. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755553/automatically-running-a-batch-file-as-an-administrator) for more ideas on how to do it. The easiest of the mentioned options is using a shortcut to your program and ticking the option "Run as administrator".

The other solution is to make a registry entry inside `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` and add a REG_SZ path to your executable as the value, and "RUNASADMIN" as data.

More info in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739459/10307457).