# Self elevating cmd or powershell script?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a script which I have to run frequently, but the exact moment is user-driven so I cannot use a scheduled task etc.

This script has to run with Admin-privileges (my account already has admin rights) so I cannot simply launch the script.
Is there anye way to "self-elevate" this script?

very simple example:

```
ECHO "I would like to have admin rights to recycle the app-pool"
pause
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Running a command as Administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690994/powershell-running-a-command-as-administrator)

Comment: Scheduled tasks can be triggered manually as well. Also, note that "run as administrator" requires that the user running the script either is a member of the administrators group, or has the credentials of an account that is. If you need to enable users to run something with elevated privileges *without* the users having actual admin access, scheduled tasks are your best bet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-Elevating Batch file (non-Admin user)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956053/self-elevating-batch-file-non-admin-user)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of self-elevation. But you are quite close to the solution. Create a task with the scheduler and then trigger it with another bat file like this:

```
SCHTASKS /U "user name" /P "password" /TN "Yourtaskname"
```

Or you can give a normal user the rights to run a task and skip `/U "user name" /P "password"`.

Comment: That sounds good, when my meeting friday is done, I will try it ;)